# Блокировка асинхронной функции C++

Tags: c++, многопоточность, boost

Всем привет! Помогите разобраться, как правильно сделать вот такую штуку на C++.

У меня есть класс, который реализует веб-сокет клиент.
Пользователь может из нескольких потоков вызывать метод отправки сообщений Send().
Этот метод кладет сообщение в очередь на отправку и вызывает SendNextRequest(),
который извлекает первое сообщение из очереди и пишет его в сокет:

```
void SendNextRequest() {
    // (1)
    // Возьмем сообщение из очереди и асинхронно запишем данные в сокет
    ws_->async_write(OnWrite);
}
```

Функция отправки сообщения SendNextRequest вызывает бустовую функцию async_write,
которая пишет данные в сокет и как только они записались, то будет вызван метод OnWrite

```
void OnWrite() {
    // Данные записались в сокет
    
    // Вот тут надо бы опять вызвать SendNextRequest()
    SendNextRequest();
    
    // (2)
}
```

Мне бы хотелось, чтобы по окончанию работы OnWrite я мог опять вызвать SendNextRequest, чтобы отправить следующее сообщение из очереди, и так пока очередь не опустеет.
Загвоздка тут в том, что изначально Send() вызывается из разных потоков, соответственно SendNextRequest тоже будет работать в разных потоках.
Каким образом я могу заблокировать SendNextRequest с начала ее выполнения (1) и до окончания выполнения OnWrite (2), чтобы все остальные потоки ждали своей очереди?

Answer (score -1):

Добавьте более детальный минимальный пример демонстрирующий проблему.
я пока могу предложить только замечательные грабли, потенциально вызывающие кучу проблем

```
void OnWrite() {
    // Данные записались в сокет
    
    std::thread t(SendNextRequest);
    t.detach();
}
```